# Write data to multiple sockets at once (one Syscall)

Tags: c, sockets, system-calls

I have a TCP-Brodcast-Server coded with libevent which does the following:

```
Read data from a client
...
Transform the data
... 
//Write data to all connected clients   
for (int i = 0; i< connected clients; i++){
    // write Syscall for every client
    write(clientfd[i], "Transformed Data", lenofdata) 

}
```

Now i want to improve performance and to reduce the count of system calls.
Instead of writing the transformed data to every socket in a sequencial way and to make a system call each time i write to a socket, i want to write the data to all of my connected clients with just one system call like this:

```
Read data from a client
...
Transform the data
... 

// one single write Syscall for all connected clients
write(arrayWithManyClientFds, "Transformed Data", lenofdata)
```

Is that possible?

EDIT:
Initially i though i found a syscall called lio_listio which is described [here](http://ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-asyn) as beeing a function which is "important because it means you can start lots of I/Os in the context of a single system call (meaning one kernel context switch)."

Unfortunalty lio_listio() seams not to be working for Sockets as it is stated [here](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html): "AIO read and write on sockets [are not supported] (doesn't return an explicit error, but quietly defaults to synchronous or rather non-AIO behavior)"

**So i am still looking for a solution, if there is one!**

Comment: Imagine a scenario where your server has two clients, one with a very fast network connection and one with a very slow network connection.  How would a (hypothetical) TCP writeMany() function handle that?

Comment: Good Point. But it could be solved with an asynchronous non blocking write() like aio_write where the Kernel handles the writing to each file descriptor. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with aio_write(), but I think it would only delay the onset of the problem.  If you're sending a large amount of data, the "current send position" for the slow and fast clients will diverge by an ever-growing amount, so either the kernel would end up having to buffer gigabytes of data in RAM (until the slow client was ready to receive it), or it would have to reduce the speed at which it sends data to the speed at which the slowest client can receive.  Neither of those would be a very satisfactory solution.

Comment: Sure there would be a divergence between slow and fast connections. But this would also be the case in the user space. If a slow connection is not ready to be written, i would need to hold back (or buffer) the data in user space before sending it to the kernel.. This would lead to even more write()-Syscalls because everytime just little data can be written to the slow connection... So in my opinion, it would be really great if there would be a possibility (syscall) to let the Kernel handle all the buffering for a bunch of connections to reduce  write()-syscalls...

Comment: If your data is coming from a file, then in user space you can handle the divergence by reading from different locations of the file as necessary for each different connection.  If it's being generated from some source whose flow rate isn't under your control (e.g. an audio or video input) then yeah, you'll have to deal with that issue no matter what.  However, I doubt write() is your bottleneck; that is, I'd bet that even if you had the solution you ask for here, that you'd notice a significant performance difference.  All write() does is copy the bytes to kernel space; it's a fast operation.

Comment: Right now i am hitting 90.000 Websocket-Messages per second on a dualcore amd with nealry 200.000 connected clients with avaiable 2GB Ram. And with such a high throughput i think i would notice it, if i could reduce all the 90.000 write syscalls per second to just one... Because its not just the data which is beeing copied from user to kernal space. Its also the cpu state which need to be saved and restored everytime a context switch needs to be done..

Comment: Huh.  What happens if you walk over to one of those clients and yank its Ethernet cable out?  i.e. how does your server handle it when one of the connected clients stops reading-and-acking its incoming TCP packets?

Comment: if any errors happen while reading data,the server closes the client connection.

Comment: In this case the server's writing, not reading, and the error isn't going to be detected for several minutes, since the server has no way of knowing that the client is physically disconnected and not just slow.  And in the meantime the server can either block waiting for the client to recover (which I doubt is acceptable for the 199,999 other clients) or buffer up the client's outgoing data until the client can receive it (which would use up lots of RAM).  Or are you treating EWOULDBLOCK as a fatal error?  If so, I'd imagine that would cause a lot of clients to get dropped unnecessarily...

Answer (score 4):

No, It's not. But if it makes you feel any better the system call only copies the data to a kernel buffer and then the operating system writes the data on the line on its own time which is IO time and significantly slower than the CPU so the performance issue here is minimal and I doubt it would become a bottleneck for you.
Another possible solution would be to use [broadcast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_%28networking%29) or [Multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) - but these solutions are problematic and blocked on most routers and networks.

One of the reasons that there is no support for such a feature is the fact that an IP packet can't be easily sent to multiple recipients - each packet contains the receivers MAC and IP addresses and each recipient could be listening on a different TCP port that is also a part of the packet, so that handling of the packet is different for each recipient and thus a loop over the sockets is required either in the kernel or the user program - And it's not a required or a reasonable feature for the kernel to implement.

Comment: You say "an IP packet can't be easily sent to multiple recipients". Not _easily_, because using broadcast addresses or multicast (that you hint at) do that, but are complex and/or don't work in practical networking environments? Could you expand?

Comment: @immortial: *"the performance issue here is minimal"*... If I'm not wrong, the kernel is free to execute pending work (e.g., softirqs) when returning from a syscall. This makes the application experience further latency that would be avoided by using one single syscall.

Answer (score 0):

If all the clients are on the same network, you could use UDP sockets with SO_BROADCAST option.

This way when one computer does a message 'send', all the other computers would 'recv' the message and update as necessary.

Also, for the same reasons that @immortal pointed out, this will not work if messages have to go through routers in order to reach clients.

You could create a set of UDP based proxies that receive the broadcast message and then each proxy would forward it to a client using TCP.  This way at least the load on the process sending the messages is reduced and shared by other computers on the network.

Comment: A slightly more refined version would use multicast packets instead of broadcast; that way (at least on networks with an intelligent switch) the UDP packets would only go to recipients that actually want to receive them.  (Broadcast packets, by contrast, always go to everything on the local network segment, which wastes bandwidth and CPU cycles)